# Proving $\det A = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, determinant

Given a real invertible $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with $A + A^{-1} = I$, I need to prove that $\det A = 1$.

I know how to prove that $\det A = \frac{1}{\det A^{-1}}$, but don't have access to the fact that the determinant of a sum is the sum of the determinants (but only multiplicativity). Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Note that $A^2-A+I=0$; for a $2\times2$ matrix, the constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial is the determinant

Comment: Are you familiar with the characteristic polynomial of a matrix?

Comment: I'm familiar with it, but I don't have access to this yet.

Comment: The determinant of a sum is not generally the sum of the determinants

Comment: Since it is a 2x2 matrix, you can get your hands dirty and rewrite the problem as a system of equations with the elements of the matrix and its inverse.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is real matrix? Since it is false for complex matrices.

Comment: Yes, assuming $A$ is real.

Answer (score 9):

Multiply both sides of $A+A^{-1}=I$ by $A$ to get $A^2+I=A$ or $A^2-A+I=0$, and note that,

for an $n\times n$ matrix, the constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^n\det(A)$.

**Addendum in response to comment:**

Here is another way.

Let $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$.  Then $A^{-1}=\dfrac{\pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}}{\det A}.$

$A+A^{-1}=I=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\implies$

$a+\dfrac d{\det A}=1=d+\dfrac a{\det A}$ and $ b-\dfrac b{\det A}=0=c-\dfrac c{\det A}$

$\implies \det A=1$ or $a-d=b=c=0$, but we can't have the latter,

since then $\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a}+\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a}^{-1}=I$ would imply $a+\dfrac1a=1$, which has no real solutions.

Comment: Though this makes sense to me, I don't have access to information about the characteristic polynomial just yet. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Another way to proceed from $A^2 - A + I = 0$ is to observe that this implies $A^3 = I$.

Comment: Everything up until the final step is fine for me, but does the possibility that $b = 0$ complicate anything? Rearranging and factoring, I get $(\det A - 1)b = 0$, so either $\det A = 1$ (the goal) or $b = 0$. If $b = 0$, I don't have the desired conclusion.

Comment: You need to consider more cases for the second argument: if $b = 0$, but $c \neq 0$, then substitute $c$ for $b$. If $b = c = 0$, then $a$ and $d$ are both non-zero and $a = d/\Delta$ and $d = a/\Delta$ imply $\Delta = 1$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler:  did you mean $A^3=-I$?

Comment: @StanleySmith:  good point

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ah yes, that would be right.

Comment: @RobArthan:  wouldn't it be $a+d/\Delta=1=d+a/\Delta$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is there a way to resolve this, or is the result not necessarily true if $b = 0$?

Comment: Yes, I got the details wrong, but I trust you agree that you need to consider these additional cases.

Comment: In the case $b=c=0$, $A$ becomes a diagonal matrix so the original equation implies $a + a^{-1} = d + d^{-1} = 1$ which is a contradiction to the assumptions since $a + a^{-1} = 1$ has no real solutions.

Comment: But what if just one of $b,c$ are $0$? This is the case I'm struggling with.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments; I edited accordingly.  Looking at all four components of the matrix equation, $\det A=1$ or $b=c=0$.

Comment: @StanleySmith If one of $b$ or $c \ne 0$, then still it's sufficient to show that $1-\frac 1{\det A} = 0$. Whether the remaining of $b$ or $c = 0$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think your corrected comment should be an answer (perhaps with a smidgen more detail).

Comment: A degree 2 annihilating polynomial of a $2\times 2$-matrix is not necessarily equal to the characteristic polynomial. Consider $A=I$ which satisfies $A^2−I=0$ but has characteristic polynomial $x^2−2x+1$. — The argument only works in this exercise because $x^2-x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$ so the minimal polynomial can't be of lower degree.

Answer (score 8):

Multiply by $A$:
$$
A^2-A+I=0
$$
Multiply by $A+I$:
$$
A^3+I=0
$$
Since $A^3=-I$, we get
$$
\det(A)^3=\det(-I)=1
$$
since the matrix is $n\times n$ for $n$ even.

$A$ is real, so $\det(A)$ is real; that is,
$$
\det(A)=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Post multiplying the equation on both sides by $A$ we get
$$A^2 -A +I=0$$
Therefore an associated annihilating polynomial is
$$p(\lambda)=\lambda^2 -\lambda +1$$
Observing that it has degree $2$ and is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ it follows that it's the characteristic polynomial.
Clearly the product of eigenvalues of $A =(-\omega)(-\omega^2)=1=det(A)$
where $\omega$ denotes a third root of unity

Edit:I really appreciate @Christoph's criticism and help in finding and ultimately trying to fill gaps.
There's another slightly different (almost made up) way, which is by noting that the characteristic polynomial associated to $A$ and $A^{-1}$ is identical which means $det(A)=det(A^{-1})=1/det(A)$ which implies we've the possibilities $det(A)=\pm1$ , we can rule out the $-1$ by looking at the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial

Comment: A degree 2 annihilating polynomial of a $2\times 2$-matrix is not necessarily equal to the characteristic polynomial. Consider $A=I$ which satisfies $A^2-I=0$ but has characteristic polynomial $x^2-2x+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but isn't the annihilating polynomial minimal when it's monic?

Comment: In the same example of $A=I$, we have $x^2-1$ as a monic annihilating polynomial but the minimal polynomial is $x-1$. The missing ingredient here is that $x^2-x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$. The minimal polynomial divides any annihilating polynomial and since we already have an irreducible one, they have to be equal.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer, but if the degrees of the annihilation polynomial and characteristic polynomial are same , then can't be conclude the eigenvalues to be zeros of the annihilation polynomial!

Comment: Of course, the minimal polynomial being of the same degree as the characteristic one implies they are equal (since they are monic and one divides the other). But to get there you need to involve irreducibility. Also note: there is not "*the* annihilating polynomial". Every matrix has an infinite set of annihilating polynomials.

Comment: Apologies ,I'm just learning linear algebra, I know that for the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial to be the same the dimension of the eigenspace must be 1, but in this case ,I don't see a way to prove this. Also can you please shed  light on how irreducibility over some structure helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126842/discussion-between-amartya-shekhar-and-christoph).